# How to detect redirect from external URI opened from Electron desktop application

Tags: reactjs, electron, facebook-login, desktop-application

I am building a react / electron desktop application with manual facebook login (`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#dialogresponse`).

With the click of a button, I open using `shell.openExternal` method the login dialog, but I need to detect this redirect and then read the access token out of the URI. I don't know how to do that (react newbee here).

Which should be the best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is to follow this tutorial: `https://competenepal.com/lets-make-a-facebook-login-system-in-electron-that-actually-works/`

I only had to implement this part:

```
var options = {
  client_id: '',
  scopes: "public_profile",
  redirect_uri: "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
};
var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 450, height: 300, show: false,
  parent: mainWindow, modal: true, webPreferences: {nodeIntegration:false} });
var facebookAuthURL = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + options.client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + options.redirect_uri + "&response_type=token,granted_scopes&scope=" + options.scopes + "&display=popup";
authWindow.loadURL(facebookAuthURL);
authWindow.show();
authWindow.webContents.on('did-get-redirect-request', function (event, oldUrl, newUrl) {
  var raw_code = /access_token=([^&]*)/.exec(newUrl) || null;
  var access_token = (raw_code && raw_code.length > 1) ? raw_code[1] : null;
  var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(newUrl);

  if(access_token) {
    FB.setAccessToken(access_token);
    FB.api('/me', { fields: ['id', 'name', 'picture.width(800).height(800)'] }, function (res) {
      console.log('response is:', res);
    });
    authWindow.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately, currently (Sept 2019), trying to oauth from electron produces a "You are trying to sign in from a browser or app that doesn't allow us to keep your account secure." response from Google. For now, I think I'll have to just use Electron.shell to open the oauth in the user's default browser.

Comment: @junvar After the redirect, how do you navigate back to the app to complete authentication?